# Awilix: Unable to resolve subclass with hard coded base class constructor parameters

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, awilix

I use the [awilix](https://github.com/jeffijoe/awilix) library for achieving DI in my nodejs express project which used ES6 and nodejs 12.x.

Let's say I have a base class and a subclass as follows

```
class MyBaseClass {
    #collectionName;

    constructor(collectionName) {
        this.#collectionName = collectionName;
    }

    getCollection() {
        return this.#collection;
    }
}

class MySubClass extends MyBaseClass {
    constructor() {
        super("users");
    }
}
```

I use awilix.InjectionMode.CLASSIC. When I try to resolve and instance of MySubClass, I get a resolution error which basically says "Could not resolve 'collectionName'". MySubClass does not need constructor parameters to be passed in order to be instantiated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you post awilix code too?

Comment: The author confirmed this to be an issue https://github.com/jeffijoe/awilix/issues/198